# Bash: Change "Title" of postscript file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a postscript file where I'd like to change the "Title" attribute before generating a pdf from it.

Following the beginning of the file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0 0 595 842
%%Title: GMT v5.1.1_r12693 [64-bit] Document from pscoast
%%Creator: GMT5
[…]
```

I now match the line `%%Title: GMT v5.1.1_r12693 [64-bit] Document from pscoast` with `^%%Title:\s.*` and like to replace everything after the colon with the content of a variable.

My non-working code so far:

```
sed "s/\(^%%Title:\)\s.*$/\1 $title/g" test_file.ps
```

My `sed` knowledge is very limited and my experimentation didn't yield anything useful so far - your help will be greatly appreciated.

All the best, Chris

EDIT: added my non-working code

Comment: 99% of the time you will use a single `sed` command: `s/.../.../`. so there isn't much to learn. show us your code.

Comment: @Karoly, I agree - the basic use of `s/…/…/` is not too difficult. However, I was unable so far to match and replace a line with a regex with variable content. Most probably I just got lost in the escaping of characters.

Comment: Show us what you've got so far

Comment: @grebneke - my non-working code so far: `sed "s/\(^%%Title:\)\s.*$/\1 $title/g" test_file.ps`

Comment: @Chris - I cannot see any errors with that - in fact it works for me: `title="somecontent"; sed -e "s/\(^%%Title:\)\s.*$/\1 $title/g" <<<"%%Title: GMT v5.1.yada yada yada"` gives me `%%Title: somecontent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the tricks for getting `sed` to work correctly is  getting the shell quoting right.  This creates a postscript file with the new title:

```
newtitle="Shiny New Title"
sed 's/^%%Title:.*/%%Title: '"$newtitle/" sample.ps >new.ps
```

This updates the postscript in place:

```
newtitle="Shiny New Title"
sed -i 's/^%%Title:.*/%%Title: '"$newtitle/" sample.ps
```

Many of the characters that one uses in `sed` expressions, like `$`, `(`, or `*`, are shell-active.  To protect them from possible shell expansion, they should be in single-quotes.  However, because one wants the shell to expand the `$newtitle` variable, it cannot be in single-quotes.  Thus, if you look carefully, you will see that the above substitute expression is in two parts, one single-quoted and one double-quoted.  Adding a space between them to make it clearer:

```
's/^%%Title:.*/%%Title: ' "$newtitle/" # Do not use this form.
```

Thus, the shell-active characters are protected by single-quotes and only the parts that we want the shell to mess with are in double-quotes

Comment: your second example works in the way I need it. Thank you very much. My mistakes where mainly in the shell quoting.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
myvar="some content"
sed -e "s/^\(%%Title:\).*/\1 $myvar/" < inputfile

# output
...
%%Title: some content
...
```